# Can you write to a python socket that is blocked on recvfrom

Tags: python, sockets

So, suppose in one thread the UDP socket is hanging on the recvfrom() call, waiting for incoming messages.
However, in another thread you would like to write through the socket to another address.

Is this possible? If not, what are my alternatives?

Comment: Yes, reading and writing sockets are independent.

Comment: did you try it? The good method to learn is to try to use it.